# rebuild a target base on target specific variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Assume that I have a target called install, which builds binaries from the whole code base.

And within the makefile I have another target called foo.src, which generates a source file "foo.src" with environmental variables, and it is needed for install.

A third target called test, which will run a bunch of tests.

So apparently test depends on install, install depends on foo.src.

I am trying to avoid regenerating file foo.src every time I build test, as foo.src is prerequisite of a lot of targets, but I still want to make sure it gets regenerated if I am directly building install.

what I've got so far:

```
BUILD_INSTALL =
install: BUILD_INSTALL = dummy
install: foo.src
    @echo "INSTALL!!!"
    @echo BUILD_INSTALL=$(BUILD_INSTALL)
    touch install

foo.src: $(BUILD_INSTALL)
    @echo "foo.src!!"
    @echo BUILD_INSTALL=$(BUILD_INSTALL)
    touch foo.src

test: install
    @echo "TEST!!!"

.PHONY: test dummy
dummy:
```

From what I can see, repeating building install does not regenerate foo.src. $(BUILD_INSTALL) does not expand to dummy as a prerequisite of foo.src when I am building install a second time.

Comment: So, you want to rebuild `foo.src` when you type `make install` on the command line, but not when `install` is a prerequisite for something else? It's probably possible, but would be ugly... I suspect rethinking the design would be a better approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt fails because of this, from the GNU make manual:

```
As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the
context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments)
```

You are trying to use the variable in a prerequisite list, which is not part of the target's recipe.

One way to do what you want is to declare `foo.src` phony if (and only if) `install` is given on the command line:

```
install: foo.src
        @echo "INSTALL!!!"
        @echo BUILD_INSTALL=$(BUILD_INSTALL)
        touch install

foo.src:
        @echo "foo.src!!"
        @echo BUILD_INSTALL=$(BUILD_INSTALL)
        touch foo.src

test: install
        @echo "TEST!!!"

ifeq (install,$(filter install,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
.PHONY: foo.src
endif
```